Flutter showModalBottomSheet in diferrent class
Let's say I have a text and button in main screen(class) and showModalBottomSheet in different class, when main screen button pressed, it will trigger showModalBottomSheet that contain a button, that button will dismissed the modal bottom sheet and change(updateUI) text in main screen.
Can you give example how I can achieve this? or showModalBottomSheet cannot use in different class when I want to update the UI?

You can try this code i hope this is a use-full
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  String _displayText = 'Initial Text';

  void _updateText(String newText) {
    setState(() {
      _displayText = newText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_displayText),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return BottomSheetWidget(updateText: _updateText);
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Text('Show Modal Bottom Sheet'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String) updateText;

  BottomSheetWidget({required this.updateText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                updateText('Updated Text');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Update Text and Close'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


You can pass anything back to the main screen by using this.
In your case we are passing String
Close the BottomSheet like this.
Navigator.of(context).pop("updated text");

In the main screen you can fetch the value like this.
onPressed: () async {
                String? result = await showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return BottomSheetWidget();
                  },
                );
                if (result != null) {
                  print(result); //updated text
                }
              },

